# php concatination and updating in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
define ("HOST", "localhost");
define("USERNAME", "root");
define("PASSWORD", "");
define("DBNAME","faltu");

$conn = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DBNAME);
$wp =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "wordpress");
$id = 16;
$query = "SELECT * FROM movies ORDER By id ASC";
                            $run = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0){
                               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
                                 $movie_name = $row['movie_name'];
                                    $star_cast = $row['star_cast'];
                                   $movie_id = $row['id'];




$content1 = '<h3><strong> '.$movie_name.' Movie Description:</strong></h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Details:</strong> </p>
<p>'.$star_cast.' </p>
<p><strong>Original Download Links  of Hindi Movie '.$movie_name.' Mp3 Songs</strong></p>
<table style="height: 395px;" width="601">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong>Movie Song Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>(128 Kbps)</strong></td>
<td><strong>(320 Kbps)</strong></td>
</tr>';
                                   $id++;
$iquery = " INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_title, post_content) VALUES ('$movie_name',  '$title') ";
    $irun = mysqli_query ($wp, $iquery); 

                                   $hquery = "SELECT * FROM songs WHERE movie_id = $movie_id";
                            $hrun = mysqli_query($conn,$hquery);
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($hrun) > 0){
                                while($hrow = mysqli_fetch_array($hrun)){
                                   $hsong_name = $hrow['song_name'];
                                   $singer = $hrow['singer_name'];
                                   $hsong_link = $hrow['song_link'];







echo $content2 ='<tr>
<td>'.$hsong_name.'
<em>'.$singer.'</em></td>
<td><strong><a href="'.$hsong_link.'">Download</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a href="'.$hsong_link.'">Download</a></strong></td>
</tr>';
echo $id;                                 
$jquery = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = CONCAT(post_content, '$content2') WHERE ID = $id";
              $jrun = mysqli_query ($wp, $jquery); 
                                    if(mysqli_num_rows($jrun) > 0){
                                    echo $content;}
}}}}
?>
```

First of all sorry for asking the dumb question, I am a big big NOOB
Ok What I am trying to do here is:

I have 2 databases I am extracting from 1st database (faltu) and adding some html with the values and putting those value in 2nd database (wordpress), in $query I am taking $movie_name and $star_cast value  and adding some html then putting it into $content1, after that inserting it into wordpress.wp_posts through iquery, now i want $hquery to give me the list of the songs where movie_id's are same, 
then i want to save that list in content2 and want to CONCATINATE that content in same wordpress.wp_posts on that same column,
I can echo these lists just fine but itsnot getting added in the database, please help me,
thanks

I want to make post content value like this

```
<h3><strong>Kaabil 2016 Movie Description:</strong></h3>
StarCast:Hrithik Roshan, Yami Gautam
Music by :Sanjay Gupta
Music<strong>:</strong> Rajesh Roshan

<strong>Original Download Links  of Hindi Movie Kaabil Mp3 Songs</strong>
<table style="height: 395px;" width="601">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong>Movie Song Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>(128 Kbps)</strong></td>
<td><strong>(320 Kbps)</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>01 –</strong> Kaabil Hoon
<em>Jubin Nautiyal,  Palak Muchhal</em></td>
<td><strong><a href="#">Download</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a href="#">Download</a></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>02 –</strong> Haseeno Ka Deewana
<em>Raftaar,  Payal Dev</em></td>
<td><strong><a href="#">Download</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a href="#">Download</a></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>03 –</strong> Kuch Din
<em>Jubin Nautiyal</em></td>
<td><strong><a href="#">Download</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a href="#">Download</a></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>04 –</strong> Mon Amour
<em>Vishal Dadlani</em></td>
<td><strong><a href="#">Download</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a href="#">Download</a></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>05 –</strong> Kaabil Hoon (Sad Version)
<em>Jubin Nautiyal</em></td>
<td><strong><a href="#">Download</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a href="#">Download</a></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>06 –</strong> Kisi Se Pyar Ho Jaye
<em>Jubin Nautiyal</em></td>
<td><strong><a href="#">Download</a></strong></td>
<td><strong><a href="#">Download</a></strong></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: look into mysql join

Comment: my best guess here missing some escaping `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: Or better yet, use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: There isn't any errors in my code?? :D :D

Comment: FIXED IT, THANKS ALL..